# How can I tell what are the maximum attribute values that are expected from the different item levels?

Tags: diablo-iii

How can I tell what are the maximum attribute values that are expected from the different item levels?
Is there a Diablo III items prefixes and suffixes list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

question like this were asked many times already. [**Here**](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/41045-spoiler-diablo-iii-item-affixes/)'s what you're looking for. It's an old list, but it still looks up-to-date.

***EDIT***

Looks like there is some encoding problems at that link. [**Here**](http://www.d3own.com/) is another one. And it looks easier

Comment: As a sidenote, if you know a question's already been asked, it's better to flag it as a duplicate rather than stating it's been asked before, and then answering it anyways.